# understand .git-ci lab file

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

```
executing-test:
  stage: test
  script:
   - apt-get update && apt-get install --quiet --assume-yes python-dev python-pip unzip wget
   - echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> 
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
  - apt update
  - apt install -y google-chrome-stable
  - cp requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
  - pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
  - CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`wget --no-verbose --output-document - 
 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`
  - wget --no-verbose --output-document /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip 
 http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver
  - chmod +x /opt/chromedriver/chromedriver
  - ln -fs /opt/chromedriver/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
  - robot -v BROWSER:HeadlessChrome -v APP_ENV:test -d rf_test/reports rf_test/test
```

can somebody please explain these commands written in a .git-ci.yaml lab file. especially where can i find this opt/chromedriver folder because it is not present in repository or where does it get installed

Answer (score 0):

This first bit installs Python, Pip and Google Chrome. And installs requirements from the `requirements.txt` file.

The next bit is the bit pertaining to the chromedriver:

```
  - CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`wget --no-verbose --output-document - 
 https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`
  - wget --no-verbose --output-document /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip 
 http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver
  - chmod +x /opt/chromedriver/chromedriver
```

The steps are:

1. Get the version from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE which is currently 80.0.3987.16
2. Then download http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip replacing $CHOMEDRIVER_VERSION with the version number from the previous step.
3. Unzip the file you downloaded into `/opt/chromedriver`
4. Make `/opt/chromedriver/chromedriver` executable.

Comment: Thankyou . But there is no opt/chromedriver folder to be found in my gitlab repo although this command did result as success when pipeline ran.

Comment: If you read my comment above, I've explained in point 3 where the `/opt/chromedriver` folder comes from.